# how to give rights to a webparts in share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am working on sharepoint 2013.I have 5 site pages which are linked to top links bars.I want to on  1 st Link..Named Ecommerce URL: http://www.123.com/layout/... is linked to it and opens page which has 5 webpart.

What i want when some user suppose Richard click on the Ecommerce Links he will able to see the webpart for which he have right.I have to give him rights to view only 3 webparts out of 5.Can it be possible.

What solution i am thinking is to make 2 Usergroup

Example 1)abc-in abc add 1 user with name of nokia 2) xyz -in xyhz add 1 user name Sony

Now I will give rights to abc when he clicks on Ecommerce to view only 1,2,3 Webpart out of 5 and to xyz user to give rights of 3,4,5 webparts.

Now how do I give rights to a user to see specific Webpart..I dont know that.I dont want to di it with code beacuse Client has no Central Administrator so I need to it with only interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by `targeting the audience` for each web part as the following

- Edit your Ecommerce page.
- Edit the webpart that you need a specific group to see it.
- in advanced section > add one or more audience names (Group) to the Target Audiences list.

[image]

- Click Ok > Stop editing the page.
- Now when the page is rendered, the Web Part appears only to the people who are members of the audiences you specified.

Comment: Just note: This is not real permissions, just hiding the information (which seems to be enough in this case)

Comment: I tried it and selected Sharepoint User group and Searched for the Name to Select and Add.But it showing that List not available.So I need to Compile the Active Directory List From Central Admin so that List will get added in  Target Audience and I will search and add it.But I came to know that client just use Sharepoint 2013 for management purpose so he has not installed Central administrator. So I am Left with 2 option  1)How can I compile User profile account of Sharepoint 2013 Users without using Central admin. 2) Is there any other way to give rights to web parts in SharePoint 2013.